# Using Polymer elements in a .Jade file

Tags: html, pug, polymer

I have just started learning Polymer and web dev. The Polymer elements load perfectly when I view the html file in my broweser. When I convert my HTML file to Jade, the jade file does not display any of the polymer elements.

HTML including Polymer elements

```
<core-drawer-panel id="drawerPanel" responsiveWidth="100px">
    <core-header-panel drawer>
        <core-toolbar id="navheader'">
```

is converted into Jade

```
core-drawer-panel#drawerPanel(responsivewidth="100px")
      core-header-panel(drawer="")
        core-toolbar#navheader
```

which does not render properly.

Does anybody know a way to get Jade to recognize custom html tags?

Comment: Can you grab the html that's being generated by the jade templating engine (e.g. by curling your server) and post it here? Polymer is generally compatible with server-side templating engines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was completely wrong with this question. One of my coworkers helped me solve the problem. Jade works fine with custom tags and web components. The error was coming from my file imports.

Comment: You might want to consider to completely remove the question in order to prevent people coming here in the false hope.